# How to extract substring of input?

Tags: regex, r

How to extract substrings from this input:

```
input = c("Inspecting sequence ID   NM_000775",    
          "Inspecting sequence ID   NM_001014975", 
          "Inspecting sequence ID   NM_001080484")
```

to get:

```
output= c("NM_000775",  "NM_001014975", "NM_001080484")
```

Comment: `read.table(text = x)[, 4]`

Comment: both work very well. Many thanks to rawr & akrun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
 sub('.*([A-Z]{2}\\_\\d+)$', '\\1', input)
 #[1] "NM_000775"    "NM_001014975" "NM_001080484"
```

Or if there are exactly 3 words followed by spaces before the last substring (to be extracted)

```
  sub('(\\w+\\s+){3}', '', input)
  #[1] "NM_000775"    "NM_001014975" "NM_001080484"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 gsub('.*\\s','',input)
```

Comment: Note that this will only work if the input is guaranteed to be in the format mentioned in the post. If there is a single trailing space, this will remove the desired portion of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)

unlist(str_extract_all(input, "NM_\\d+"))
#[1] "NM_000775"    "NM_001014975" "NM_001080484"
```

As akrun mentioned, you could also avoid `unlist()` by simply using `str_extract()`:

```
str_extract(input, "NM_\\d+")
#[1] "NM_000775"    "NM_001014975" "NM_001080484"
```

The regular expression used, `NM_\\d+`, will match anything beginning with `NM_` followed by one or more digits.

Depending on whether `NM_` is specific to the example or is representative of your actual problem, you may want to generalize the regular expression to `[A-Z]{2}_\\d+` or, as akrun mentioned, `\\w+_\\d+`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sub("Inspecting sequence ID\\s+","",input)
[1] "NM_000775"    "NM_001014975" "NM_001080484"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming NM is what identifies the entry, another possibility is

```
gsub(".*\\s*(NM_\\d+)$", "\\1", input)
```